# Quality Measurement

Tags: language-agnostic

Suppose we are using DPMO system of quality and if a person has done 100 points and the opportunity is 9 and the person has got 10 qfails out of 70 as 70 transaction got selected for quality audit, then what would be the formula of measuring his quality by DPMO system ?   10 errors  , 100 transactions , 9 opportunity per transaction, transaction QC'd 70?

Answer (score 1):

`DPMO = (1,000,000 * number of defects)/(number of units * number of opportunities)`

What does that give you?